# What typeface or style is this font?

Tags: typesetting

Does anyone know what typeface or style this is?

[image]

Comment: I'd say we don't do identification of fonts, but maybe people are ok with identifying typefaces. We do have questions like http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25345/1628

Comment: nevermind.. I already found it..

Comment: [金文体]{きんぶんたい} https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E9%87%91%E6%96%87%E4%BD%93+%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88&biw=1093&bih=510&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio_7vetK7PAhVBwpQKHUQBB5sQ_AUIBigB と呼ばれるフォントだそうですね・・

Comment: Mr. サムソン マルテーン -- How did you find it? That's a nice font. ( What is it called?   ) This one is somewhat similar  http://www.flopdesign.com/freefont/utsukushi-mincho-font.html

Comment: @chocolate DF金文体に直感のイメージは近いんですが明らかに違うフォントです…なんだろう

Comment: @naruto あら、ちょっと違う・・・？（私、そういうのホントに詳しくないから・・）

Answer (score 4):

It's [ライラ](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/item?LyraStd-DB) from フォントワークス (Fontworks), but the example has been kerned tighter.

Sample:

[image]

---

**BONUS**
As mentioned in comments, this typeface bears an obvious similarity with a preceding font [DF金文体](http://font.designers-garage.jp/ds/execute/FontSearch?encoding=Shift_JIS&locale=ja&tick=1440484101141&node=1440484076808&createOrder=false&searchType=1&orderBy=id&desc=false&knownTotal=0&offset=0&simString=%8DU%8Ak%8B%40%93%AE%91%E0&category=0&maker=0&weight=0&type=0&platform=0&keyword=%8B%E0%95%B6%91%CC&simulation=2&saleType=1), which also is likely to be its source of inspiration.

金文体 is [officially](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/product/product_download_detail.aspx?sid=68) introduced as an adaptation of the design seen in inscriptions on an ancient vessel [中山王方壺](https://hsiangming.blogspot.jp/2014/12/blog-post_23.html) to modern script, and carries a unique, "sublimating" atmosphere that makes it famous since been used in a visual novel game.

Note that, as the style of 中山王方壺 is likewise unique among its contemporaries, despite the name 金文体, the typeface doesn't particularly resemble average 金文 "[bronze script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)".

Compared to 金文体, ライラ has less calligraphic features from the inscriptions on the vessel, thus to give out a more exotic rather than mystic feel.

Comment: Maybe you could also comment on the more general font features: e.g. the fact that the *kanji* seem to be a type of (faux) seal script and the shapes of the *hiragana/katakana* are completely new inventions. (Provided what I said is correct—I'm sure you know the answer, though.)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Well... I'll try.

Comment: I think this sort of answer makes this a good "thread" (even though the question score is the second lowest one of all currently existing questions...).

Comment: @Earthliŋ Maybe OP should have asked this on Graphic Design SE.