# Need help on translating

Tags: katakana, hiragana

[image]

I am confused with this, I am new to Japanese and I am still learning it, but isn't this supposed to mean "Tawapon Sanha?" ?, also why is the Sa symbol different from the usual symbol that is this "さ" and I know what Tawapon means I think it is a name but Sanha on the other hand, can anyone tell me what it means?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25345/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend plugging phrases like this into [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AF%E3%83%9D%E3%83%B3%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%AF) to help you get the breakdown of the characters.

さん written in hiragana is typically the standard honorific marker. It tells you that the katakana before it is a name and that can translate to "Mr. Tawapon" or "Ms. Tawapon".

は is a topic marker particle and it is pronounced like "wa" when used as a particle. It just indicates that Mr. Tawapon is the topic of your sentence, and since it ends with a question mark it's like saying "As for Mr. Tawapon?" This question could mean a lot of things so it's important to know the full context for a better translation.

As for the way さ is written, it's exactly the same as さ. It is just a different handwriting style, similar to how English has print and cursive style.

Comment: Thank you for giving me some explanation, I will take note of your advices.